# detecting how much of a div is beyond window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, height

I have a fixed div that I want to sit on top of a number of background images. The issue is that if this fixed div is taller than the window, it wont scroll, meaning content is lost. I've tried using `max-height: 100%` and `y-overflow:scroll;` but no luck.

I have figured a workaround using the following javascript:

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var css = {};
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() > 120){
         css = { top:'0'};
    } 
    else {
            css = {top:'120'};
    }
    $('#writtenContent').animate(css,{duration:200,queue:false});
  });
</script>
```

Which moves it up, but this is not ideal for a number of reasons. Id like to either be able to know how much of the div is hidden, and then move up that amount, or have the fixed div scrollable. Ideally either of these should only happen if necessary i.e. if the div fits in the window, then no action taken.

Any ideas would be great!

===============UPDATE=================

Hi guys - here is a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKks8/9/) showing the type of thing. Its a stripped down version, but shows the problem Im having. If the window is resized to be smaller than the content holding div, we loose it.

Comment: Hmm you said that it's a fixed div, which generally means `position:fixed` but then you say `position:relative`? What do those refer to?

Comment: can you post more code that helps this be relevant? perhaps set up a codepen or fiddle? It may be an issue with the html or css... and this script may be unnecessary... just a thought

Answer (score 0):

Ok well first off, you said that it's a fixed div, which generally means `position:fixed` but then you say `position:relative`? What do those refer to? But it really should be scrolling. You said you tried `y-overflow` but of course that won't work. It's `overflow-y` with the y after. Try that again and see if it works. If it doesn't work then you will need to post all of the relevant code and styles so we can see what is going on.

Also it's somewhat hackish but try using `max-height:` with varying percentages less than 100% to see if it works even a little bit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this will work for you.

```
var win             = window,
    $writtenContent = $('#writtenContent'),
    $writtenContentPosition;

function windowScrollMagic(){

    $writtenContentPosition = $writtenContent.offset().top; // get elements distance from top

    // if you've scrolled farther than the elements position:

    if (win.scrollY > $writtenContentPosition) {

        // do something, like animating $writtenContent to the win.scrollY coordinate
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(win).scroll(){

        windowScrollMagic();
    });
});
```

---

Update in response to example jsfiddle:

```
var $win            = $(window),
    $winHeight,
    $writtenContent = $('#writtenContent'),
    $writtenContentPosition,
    $writtenContentHeight,
    $writtenContentBottomEdgePosition,
    heightDifference;

function calculateHeights() {

    $winHeight                        = $win.height();
    $writtenContentPosition           = $writtenContent.offset().top;
    $writtenContentHeight             = $writtenContent.height();
    $writtenContentBottomEdgePosition = $writtenContentPosition + $writtenContentHeight;

    heightDifference                  = $winHeight - $writtenContentBottomEdgePosition;
}

function windowResizeMagic() {

    calculateHeights();

    if (heightDifference < 0) {

        $('#alert').html('Written Content is off screen by ' + heightDifference + 'px');
    } else {
        $('#alert').html('Written Content is not off screen');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    calculateHeights();

    $win.resize(function(){

        windowResizeMagic();
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry I couldnt manage to get this to work. It looks like it should do what Im after, but didnt seem to have an effect?

Comment: @user3462105 it doesn't have an application written, just offers a handle to do it in. So - in `windowScrollMagic()` within the `if` statement, write whatever you'd like it to do. Based on what I understand your question to mean, you could add something like the below to animate `$writtenContent` to the new position:

`$writtenContent.animate({scrollTop: win.scrollY}, 200);`

Comment: thanks for the reply @technopeasant - did you manage to get this working in the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry @PSK, just seeing this. Looks like you were going for something pretty different. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tKks8/121/